# RNAseq without depletion?

Tags: rna-seq

I have been asked by my supervisor to conduct an RNAseq without experimentally depleting the samples. However I am quite unsure regarding how much sequencing depth per sample I would require in order to map a decent percentage of the ORFs if I were to proceed this way.

Has anyone ever done RNAseq w/o depletion and with what results? Would you go on with it or should I make the case for depleting even though it's gonna be more expensive.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome, there's not enough information in your post to allow a comprehensive answer in my opinion. RNAseq of which species is quite key here.

Comment: Did they want you to do poly-A enrichment instead? What is the actual goal? What is the organism?

Comment: Hi, I just realized I did not mention I am working with plant **endopythic bacteria**, so no chances of using poly-A enrichment. The species is _Acidovorax facilis_, with the goal of assessing differential expression when exposed to different root exudates.